# Best Practice to always throw OperationCanceledException?

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

To put a task in the cancelled state the task should always throw an `OperationCanceledException` when cancelled. Otherwise task continuation will not work, right?

Then why do you find a lot of examples in the internet that just check the `IsCancellationRequested` flag of the `CancellationToken` and die a silent death.

Is it Best Practice to **always throw an OperationCancelledException** or is it legit in some special cases to just check the `IsCancellationRequested` flag and end the Task without throwing an OperationCancelledException?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the recommended usage would be to call the [ThrowIfCancellationRequested method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) of the [CancellationToken struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken). That will test if a cancellation has been requested and will throw a [OperationCanceledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception) a cancellation has been requested.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. That's not the point, I know how to do it. The question is if an OperationCancelledException has to be thrown always, with no exception to the rule, or, during e.g. shutting down the program if checking the flag and not throwing the exception is legit.

Comment: Then, the calling code would "think" the operation hadn't been canceled. Wouldn't it?